# What are good ways to extract price ,mileage and location from auto-dealer website?

Tags: c#, java, machine-learning

I have crawled some auto websites and  trying to extract information from these sites.
I need following information - Vin, mileage,price and location.
I tried for regular expression approach but  it do not scale since i have around 20000 websites to
extract. I want to try machine learning for extraction.

Some context : The all webpages i have downloaded have vins.I have used regex to find out that.
In some webpages , price is represented as any of the following words - price,market price , eprice, internet price,MSRP.
there are some price texts which are stroked out and another lower price is offered as in case of discount.I want my program to take this into consideration and ignore stroked out price consider the other price.
Mileage is represented as mileage or  miles.

I thought of using wrapper induction , but read that approach would not work if the website changes the template of the site.
Moreover, that approach takes time to train a classifier per pattern per website.

So what kind of approach or algorithm i should use to extract price mileage and location from  a webpage.

Comment: *"What are good ways to extract price ,mileage and location from auto-dealer website?"*  Using the API they provide for programatically accessing their info.  If they don't provide an API, it might be they are sending you a message.

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to parse a html site:

1. you can use [Regex](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet)
2. [XPath](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9494/Manipulate-XML-data-with-XPath-and-XmlDocument-C) also can be used to select the content
3. But the best way will be to use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

**HTML Agility Example:**

```
var doc = new HtmlWeb().Load(url);
var comments = doc.Descendants("div")
                  .Where(div => div.GetAttributeValue("class", "") == "comment");
```

[Here](http://olussier.net/2010/03/30/easily-parse-html-documents-in-csharp/) you can find a overview of different methods to parse HTML-fields via C# (including examples)

Comment: @AndrewThompson lost the hyperlink

Answer (score 0):

You may take a look at [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). It allows you to parse HTML and extract the necessary information using CSS selectors. It could make your code somehow more resilient to changes of the design and structure of the website.